# multiprocessing process gets started directly at creation

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Hi I have a problem with multiprocessing in python 3.7
I've made a listener, that should be waiting for a response from a server without blocking the rest of the program (asynchronous communication):

```
self = cl.appendSend('bar', base_list)
print("client erstellt neuen nebenläufigen listener, für die Antwort des Servers")
multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target = cl.appendResponse(), args=(self))
process.start()
print("listener aktiv")

thread = threading.Thread(target= waitingPrinter(), args=(process, queue))
print(thread)
```

is where everything is started
but the line `process = multiprocessing.Process(target = cl.appendResponse(), args=(self))` is started once, runs through and then after being done, it just runs again. The debugger never leaves this line.

The method run in the process is:

```
 def appendResponse(self):
        print("nebenläufiger listener aktiv")
        msgrcv = self.chan.receive_from(self.server)
        print("nebenläufiger listener hat Antwort erhalten")
        return msgrcv  # pass it to caller
```

Sadly becaus of copyright I can't really post more, but the method runs through fine the first time and fails the second with the message :
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
> File "D:/Verteile Systeme 2/neues Lab/git/vs2lab/lab2/rpc/runcl.py",
> line 27, in <module>
>     process = multiprocessing.Process(target = cl.appendResponse(), args=(self))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 82, in
> __init__
>     self._args = tuple(args) TypeError: 'Client' object is not iterable
```

So I am wondering, why is the process with `cl.appendResponse()` even started upon binding to the process and doesn't wait for `process.start()` and if not already in the answer to that, why does it then run directly a second time. And of course how can I fix that.

Also is there a way to replaces processing with thread and still get a return value?
I am having a lot of trouble with processing and return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the the apparent immediate execution of the process has been correctly stated by philipp in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256882/4134674).
The `target` argument to [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Process) takes a callable object, that is to be invoked by the `run()` method. Your code passes whatever is returned by `self.chan.receive_from(self.server)`.
There is no subprocess running in or from the line `process = multiprocessing.Process(target = cl.appendResponse(), args=(self))`. Your method runs in the main process and blocks it.
On a side note: you will have the exact same issue with your [`thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#threading.Thread), for the same reason: `thread = threading.Thread(target= waitingPrinter(), args=(process, queue))`

After your method has finished executing in the main process, the initialization of your process object raises the [`TypeError` inside the `__init__` method of the `BaseProcess` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L82).
You pass an argument, `self`, to your process, but you do it incorrectly. The `args` argument requires a tuple of arguments. The creation of a tuple through a literal needs a trailing comma if only a single value is specified: `args=(self,)`. Your code effectively passes `self`, i.e. a `Client` object directly, which is not iterable and thus causes the error.
In your case, `appendResponse` appears to be a bound method of the `Client` object. It will receive the `self` argument through the inner workings of Python's class system. Passing it explicitly through the process will raise another `TypeError` for passing two positional arguments to a method that only takes one. Unless `appendSend` returns something else than the `Client` instance `cl`, that you call it on, drop the `args` parameter in the process instantiation.

On another side note: the start method `spawn` is the only one available on Windows and thus the default. Unless your code needs to run under Unix using that start method, this line is redundant: `multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")`

Comment: Thanks it is good to know what is wrong and also that I did send the arguments the wrong way.
I changed it and will try it tomorrow when I can get contact to the server again.
Since you seem to understand the workings of python way better than I do, I wonder what do you think of my construction, that the thread is getting the response of the process and then prints it out.
My assumption is that the thread will be started and does nothing as the rest of the program continues to run and only starts when the process returns a response.
Am I correct with that assumption?

Comment: @Etaila That's a bit hard to tell, since I don't know what happens in `waitingPrinter`, but from what I understand from your description, your assumption seems correct. However, since your process simply appears to wait for some data from a server, why not drop it completely and do everything in the thread? The process' task seems to be I/O bound, so Pythons Global Interpreter Lock should not be an issue here. When you pass your `Client` object directly into `waitingPrinter` you could call the method inside it and directly process the result, once received.

Comment: @ shmee The waitingPrinter just uses process.join and 'print()' to write the response in the console nothing more.
And the reason I split these two is that the process comes from another class that only handles the communication to the server, the print of the result, or in a real task, the further handling of the response is a different class, where the waitingPrinter is defined in. And I don't feel comfortable, basicly scrapping the client complete within the context of the task.
If it would have been a private project I probably would have done all within the process.

Comment: @Etaila Oh, and now, that I looked even closer, you don't have to pass that argument to your process instantiation. In fact, it will raise another `TypeError` when `process.start()` is called. `appendResponse` seems to be a bound method of your `Client` object, so it will be passed as such. It will receive the instance referenced in `self` internally. Passing `self` again will have you end up with the method being called with two positional arguments, while it only accepts one.

Answer (score 3):

`target = cl.appendResponse()` will run the function and return the result to target.
The correct syntax would be `target=cl.appendResponse` which will tell Process to run cl.appendResponse on start().